# Adding NSMutableArray A to NSMutableArray B, and then doing "removeAllObjects" on A, clears B too?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
A = bookmarkArray
B = issueArray              
[issueArray addObject:bookmarkArray];
[bookmarkArray removeAllObjects];
```

Why does this leave issueArray empty, and what can I do to make sure I still have issueArray populated when bookmarkArray is cleared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add bookmarkArray directly to issueArray. So then issueArray is an array holding a single object, which is the array bookmarkArray. If you mutate bookmarkArray then you mutate the thing in issueArray.

If you mean to add all the objects currently in bookmarkArray to issueArray then I'd suggest:

```
[issueArray addObjectsFromArray:bookmarkArray];
```

If you want to take a copy of bookmarkArray and add it to issueArray then I'd suggest exactly the same thing taskinoor has already suggested:

```
NSMutableArray *bookmarkCopy = [bookmarkArray mutableCopy];
[issueArray addObject:bookmarkCopy];
[bookmarkCopy release];
```

Or:

```
NSMutableArray *bookmarkCopy = [bookmarkArray copy];
[issueArray addObject:bookmarkCopy];
[bookmarkCopy release];
```

If you don't need the copy to be mutable.

Answer (score 4):

Its because when you call `addObject` it adds the reference, not a copy of the object. And thus any change in the original object will be reflected in the reference stored in array. If you want to store a copy of the object then made a copy of it and store in array.

```
NSMutableArray *bookmarkCopy = [bookmarkArray mutableCopy];
[issueArray addObject:bookmarkCopy];
[bookmarkCopy release];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that they could be referencing the same objects. Can you check if they are?

Answer (score 0):

Explanations from Tommy and taskinoor are right on the money. However, if your goal is for issueArray to contain the objects that are in bookmarkArray, do this:

```
[issueArray addObjectsFromArray:bookmarkArray];
[bookmarkArray removeAllObjects];
```

Make sure you're clear on the difference. In taskinoor's code, you're adding one object to bookmarkArray, and that object is itself an array. In the lines above, you're adding `[bookmarkArray count]` objects to issueArray.